# Return number from a collection in a non-sequential, not random and non-repeating way

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have a large sequence of integers (1M+).

Whenever a user queries my API, I need to pick one of these integers in a non-sequential, not random and non-repeating way. I cannot store the history of all integers previously returned.

I came up with a "shaking" algorithm which simply moves values around within a very large array:

```
            static int[] Shake(
                int[] values,
                Func<int, bool> predicate,
                Func<int, int> moveBy)
            {
                static int Adjust(int index, int size)
                {
                    while (index > size - 1) index -= size;
                    while (index < 0) index += size;
                    return index;
                }

                var count = values.Length;
                for (var oldIndex = 0; oldIndex < count - 1; oldIndex++)
                {
                    if (!predicate(oldIndex)) continue;

                    var newIndex = Adjust(oldIndex + moveBy(oldIndex), count);

                    var value = values[oldIndex];
                    values[oldIndex] = values[newIndex];
                    values[newIndex] = value;
                }

                return values;
            }

            var indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, size).ToArray();

            indexes = Shake(indexes, idx => idx % 3 == 0, idx => idx + 50);
            indexes = Shake(indexes, idx => idx % 2 == 0, idx => 12);

            return indexes;
```

This algorithm works and but is not really efficient:

1. I need to create and loop through large collections of items
2. May consume lots of memory / CPU
3. This is a fairly slow algorithm

Instead of creating large arrays of data, I was wondering if there is another way to return a number in a 
non-sequential, not random and non-repeating way (maybe a formula / mathematical series but my math sucks).

Thx for your help

Comment: What does "non-sequential, not random" mean to you? The example you've given seems fairly random (though a very predictable kind of randomness). Why is [Random.Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.8) not good enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an efficient and simple solution, you just need a prime number and remember n, the next time you need to increment n.

```
class Program
{

    const long prime = 15_485_863;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int  arrayLenght = 1_000_0000;

        var numbers = new int[arrayLenght];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = i;
        }

        var hashSet = new HashSet<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            var number = GetNonSequentialNotRandomNonRepeatingNumber(numbers, i);
            if (hashSet.Add(number) == false)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Something went wrong. {number} is duplicated");
            }
        }
    }

    static int GetNonSequentialNotRandomNonRepeatingNumber(int[] numbers, int n)
    {
        int pos = (int) ((prime * (long) n) % numbers.Length);
        return numbers[pos];
    }
}
```